# MvvmCross Android Switch Compound Button Bindability

Tags: user-interface, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

In a simple Monodroid/Mvvmcross project my bindings for a switch do not trigger and I have to use a workaround to complete the behavior.
I heard from a college, but am unable to find confirmation that Monodroid doesn't support switches properly yet. Thus I am wondering if this carries to Mvvmcross bindings.

Is MvvmCross unable to bind to a Switch compound button?

Code

SettingsView.axml

```
<FrameLayout [...]>
    <ScrollView [...]>
        <LinearLayout [...]>
            <Switch
                android:id="@+id/userSettingsView_Button"
                local:MvxBind="Checked ButtonChecked" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FFrameLayout>
```

SettingsViewModel.cs

```
public class SettingsViewModel : MvxViewModel {
    [...]

    public bool ButtonChecked {
        get [...] set{[...]; RaisePropertyChanged(() => ButtonChecked);}
    }
}
```

I have a version that the axml uses a checked button for legacy android version and the binding (/s/Switch/ToggleButton) works fine.
This setup I get a MvxBind error: 6.07 View type not found - Switch.

Answer (score 0):

`CompoundButton` binding for `Checked` with `CheckedChange` is implemented via https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/blob/v3/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Target/MvxCompoundButtonCheckedTargetBinding.cs and this is in place for any class inheriting from `CompoundButton`

If you find an issue, then reproducing it and logging it with either Xamarin (for a Xamarin issue) or MvvmCross (for an MvvmCross issue) - but I'm not sure anyone will be able to assist without a sample which reproduces the problem(s).

Comment: Is the code I added sufficient to understand the problem better? Easily reproducible now.

Comment: Tested - binding works fine here on JellyBean. You are targeting API Level >= 14?

Comment: Target is 18. Would the minimum version (I have it as 10 with a layout that uses togglebutton except for v14+) affect it?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that you added the Switch in your LinkerPleaseInclude.cs.
Maybe it will be stripped out during binding..

```
public void Include(Switch cb)
{
  cb.CheckedChange += (sender, args) => cb.Checked = !cb.Checked;
}
```